# CPU utilisation calculation

Tags: cpu, instructions

A CPU executes , on average 60 machine instructions per μs. suppose that a program process a file of record where reading and writing a record from a file takes 10 μs each. if the program needs to execute 120 machine instructions between each read and write operation, what is the CPU utilization?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? We're not going to just do your homework for you.

Comment: I would love a harddrive that could write a record in 10μs!

Comment: Can any of the reads/writes happen in parallell with any instructions?

Comment: Wait, I want a CPU that fast too!